# No HMDI audio using Raspberry OS on RPI4

Tags: pi-4, hdmi, audio-playback, raspberry-pi-os-bookworm

Installed Raspberry OS on my PI4 and I cant seem to get the hdmi audio to work.

1. I am using HDMI-1
2. Disabled the onboard audio
3. Tried amixer commands
4. Audio Settings in the rapi-config using pipewire. But read "no internal audio devices found"

My RPI4 configuration can be seen [here](https://paste.debian.net/hidden/e4cb4fea/)
But to quote

### System Information

Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.5

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux" 
VERSION_ID="12"
VERSION="12 (bookworm)"
```

Raspberry Pi reference 2023-10-10

Generated using pi-gen, https://github.com/RPi-Distro/pi-gen, 962bf483c8f326405794827cce8c0313fd5880a8, stage4

```
Linux raspberrypi 5.10.63v64 #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Sep 30 16:07:48 UTC
2021 aarch64 GNU/Linux 
Revision    : d03115 
Serial      : 10000000545dbb21
Model       : Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.5
Throttled flag  : throttled=0x0 
Camera          : supported=1 detected=0, libcamera interfaces=0
```

### Videocore information

```
Oct 17 2023 15:40:00  Copyright (c) 2012 Broadcom version
30f0c5e4d076da3ab4f341d88e7d505760b93ad7 (clean) (release) (start_x)
 
alloc failures:     0 compactions:        0 legacy block fails: 0
```

### Package version information

```
raspberrypi-ui-mods:   Installed: 1.20231206 
raspberrypi-sys-mods:   Installed: 20231127 
openbox:   Installed: 3.6.1-10+rpt1 
lxpanel:   Installed: 0.10.1-2+rpt19 
pcmanfm:   Installed: 1.3.2-1+rpt18 
rpd-plym-splash:   Installed: 0.37
```

### Display Information

Running (F)KMS and X

```
connector[89]: HDMI-A-1     
crtc=crtc-0     
self_refresh_aware=0
```

### config.txt

```
arm_64bit=1
arm_freq=1500
audio_pwm_mode=514
camera_auto_detect=-1
config_hdmi_boost=5
core_freq=500
core_freq_min=200
disable_commandline_tags=2
disable_l2cache=1
disable_overscan=1
display_hdmi_rotate=-1
display_lcd_rotate=-1
dvfs=3
enable_gic=1
force_eeprom_read=1
force_pwm_open=1
framebuffer_ignore_alpha=1
framebuffer_swap=1
gpu_freq=500
gpu_freq_min=250
init_uart_clock=0x2dc6c00
lcd_framerate=60
mask_gpu_interrupt0=1024
mask_gpu_interrupt1=0x10000
max_framebuffers=-1
over_voltage_avs=-20000
pause_burst_frames=1
pciex4_reset=1
program_serial_random=1
ramfsaddr=-1
total_mem=8192
hdmi_force_cec_address:0=65535
hdmi_force_cec_address:1=65535
hdmi_force_hotplug:0=1
hdmi_group:0=1
hdmi_mode:0=34
hdmi_pixel_freq_limit:0=0x11e1a300
hdmi_pixel_freq_limit:1=0x11e1a300
device_tree=-
kernel=kernel_rpi64.img
overlay_prefix=overlays/
ramfsfile=bbloader.img
hdmi_cvt:0=
hdmi_cvt:1=
hdmi_edid_filename:0=
hdmi_edid_filename:1= 
hdmi_timings:0= 
hdmi_timings:1=
```

### cmdline.txt

```
coherent_pool=1M 8250.nr_uarts=0 snd_bcm2835.enable_headphones=0 clk_ignore_unused video=HDMI-A-1:1920x1080M@30D smsc95xx.macaddr=D8:3A:DD:48:C6:2F vc_mem.mem_base=0x3ec00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x40000000 elevator=deadline quiet bootmenutimeout=15 datadev=UUID=808ddfa6-e436-4661-9ac5-3555a387bf19
```

### vcdbg log messages

```
004420.504: HDMI1:EDID error reading EDID block 0 attempt 0
004421.519: HDMI1:EDID giving up on reading EDID block 0
004429.779: brfs: File read: /mfs/sd/config.txt
004920.291: gpioman: gpioman_get_pin_num: pin DISPLAY_DSI_PORT not defined
004922.805: *** Restart logging
004922.826: brfs: File read: 654 bytes
004991.542: hdmi: HDMI1:EDID error reading EDID block 0 attempt 0
004992.559: hdmi: HDMI1:EDID giving up on reading EDID block 0
004997.599: hdmi: HDMI1:EDID error reading EDID block 0 attempt 0
004998.615: hdmi: HDMI1:EDID giving up on reading EDID block 0
004998.634: hdmi: HDMI:hdmi_get_state is deprecated, use hdmi_get_display_state instead
004998.649: HDMI0: hdmi_pixel_encoding: 300000000
012629.652: vchiq_core: vchiq_init_state: slot_zero = 0xcf000000, is_master = 1
012633.001: hdmi: HDMI:hdmi_get_state is deprecated, use hdmi_get_display_state instead
012639.734: TV service:host side not connected, dropping notification 0x00000002, 0x00000001, 0x00000022
014191.206: hdmi: HDMI:hdmi_get_state is deprecated, use hdmi_get_display_state instead
021951.920: TV service:host side not connected, dropping notification 0x00000008, 0x00000004, 0x00000000
030565.948: TV service:host side not connected, dropping notification 0x00000008, 0x00000004, 0x00000000
```

Comment: Your question is far from clear BUT if you have kernel 5.10 you have probably done something questionable.

Comment: @Milliways i'm using a berryboot install so as to load from external SSD

Comment: In other words you are NOT running Raspberry Pi OS Bookworm. Debian Bookworm was a small update BUT the Raspberry Pi OS version included massive changes - incompatible with older kernels/firmware. You are on your own.